# Pass ENV variables specified in shell from docker-compose to Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I would like to set the `DEPLOY_ENV` environment variable when I build my Docker image, but the value doesn't seem to be making it to the Dockerfile. Here's my build command:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      - DEPLOY_ENV=${DEPLOY_ENV:-development}
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
```

When I run `DEPLOY_ENV=staging docker-compose config`, I can see that it replaces the DEPLOY_ENV variable as expected:

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: /home/user/app
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b
      '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      DEPLOY_ENV: staging
    ports:
    - published: 3000
      target: 3000
    volumes:
    - /home/user/app:/app:rw
version: '3'
```

However, I can't figure out how to populate the value in my Dockerfile. Here's a Dockerfile I'm using to test:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV RAILS_ENV=${DEPLOY_ENV}
ENV NODE_ENV=${DEPLOY_ENV}
ENV APP_HOME=/app

LABEL app=app
LABEL environment=${RAILS_ENV}

RUN echo ${DEPLOY_ENV}
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, it doesn't dipslay the value of `DEPLOY_ENV`:

```
Building web
[+] Building 1.4s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.55kB                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.7.2                                                                                                                          1.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/ruby:2.7.2@sha256:1dd0106849233fcd913b7c4608078fa1a5sd5e3ce1af2a55e4d726b0d8868e2f                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] RUN echo ${DEPLOY_ENV}                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:27e159270471d3078fff8eb4eads7e4e586b345bfa13d3bdb3ec317266678549                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/app_web
```

I plan to set secret values when building my image and want to avoid hardcoding the values or use build args since they can be exposed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize the `args` primitive in docker compose, which passes build variables in your Dockerfile

```
args:
  DEPLOY_ENV_ARG: ${DEPLOY_ENV:-development}
environment:
  - DEPLOY_ENV=${DEPLOY_ENV:-development}
```

And in your Dockerfile

```
ARG DEPLOY_ENV_ARG
ENV RAILS_ENV=${DEPLOY_ENV_ARG}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this show the `DEPLOY_ENV_ARG` in the build image history?

Comment: @Alexander Didn't test that part I will provide feedback when possible. If it solved the issue, I would appreciate the upvote & approval :)

Comment: I just tested, and it did solve the issue; thank you! I think I can specify my secrets in the `environment` key for use by the application, not the Dockerfile. So they shouldn't be leaked in the Docker build image history. If I used my secrets in the args, it seems they would be leaked.